# inject svelte components into existing app?

Tags: laravel, svelte

Is it possible to integrate several components (galleries) in an existing project (laravel)? I tried with one and it is not a problem (in frontend), but with several I do not know exactly how it will be implemented by the backend.

[image]

I guess I will have to pour the information into the component with json. And each component (gallery) separately will have to be integrated
(like->

```
import Component from './Component.svelte';
new Component ({
  target: document.querySelector ('. app')
});
```

)

I will be very grateful if someone gives me a direction to go ..

**EDIT(MORE ЕXPLANATION):**

Hello again. I use web pack and gulp to configure Svelte. The idea is to replace the galleries in an existing project.

**My JSON file:**

```
{
  "top_offers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "imgs": [
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_2.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_3.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "imgs": [
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_4.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_5.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_6.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "imgs": [
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_7.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_8.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://static.barnes-bulgaria.com/property-images/big/747121_9.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Component (Houses.svelte)**

```
<script>
  import { topOffers } from "./topOffers.js";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import SwiperCore, { Lazy, Navigation } from "swiper";

  SwiperCore.use([Lazy, Navigation]);

  let Swiper;
  let SwiperSlide;

  onMount(async () => {
    let res = await fetch("json/rentahome.json");
    res = await res.json();
    $topOffers = res.top_offers;

    const SwiperSvelteModule = await import("swiper/svelte");
    Swiper = SwiperSvelteModule.Swiper;
    SwiperSlide = SwiperSvelteModule.SwiperSlide;
  });
  
</script>

{#each $topOffers as gallery (gallery.imgs)}
  <svelte:component
    this={Swiper}
    style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff;--swiper-pagination-color: #fff"
    lazy={true}
    navigation={true}
    loop={true}
    preloadImages={true}
    class="mySwiper"
    grabCursor={true}
  >

    {#each gallery.imgs as imgs (imgs.url)}
      <svelte:component this={SwiperSlide}>
        <img data-src={imgs.url} class="swiper-lazy size-img" alt="" />
        <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white" />
      </svelte:component>
    {/each}

  </svelte:component>
{/each}

<style>
  .size-img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML of existing project:**

```
 <div class="slider-slick-cardd">
           <div class='svelte' svelte-id='1'></div>
          </div>
```

Here I give an attribute to each wrapper (svelte-id = '1 ", svelte-id =' 2 '..etc), it is assumed that they are ids from JSON

**My svelte.js file:**

```
import Houses  from './Houses.svelte';
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.svelte')).forEach((e,i) => {          
   new Houses({
    target: e 
});
});
```

Here it is assumed that they should be caught by attributes..
This solution does not work as expected because the foreach component every time and the result is obtained below in the attached image

[image]

Тhe desired result must be the gallery column to be row (for each wrapper svelte-id = "1" (2,3 ..etc) attribute.

**Please someone help** :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you'll want to know the `svelte-id` inside each svelte component, so, you create 1 svelte component for each row, and showing only 1 gallery.

you can get the attribute using element.getAttribute()

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.svelte')).forEach((e,i) => {          
   const svelteId = e.getAttribute('svelte-id');

   new Houses({
    target: e,
    props: {
      offerId: svelteId
    }
   });
}
```

with that, you can handle that in your Svelte component:

```html
<script>
  import { topOffers } from "./topOffers.js";
  export let offerId;
  // ....
</script>

{#each $topOffers[offerId] as gallery (gallery.imgs)}
  <svelte:component ... />
{/each}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent long days looking for a solution. You are a legend!

Edit: {#each $topOffers[offerId] as gallery (gallery.imgs)}
  <svelte:component ... />
{/each}
gives me a error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at create_fragment"

Thats why i check with:
{#each $topOffers as gallery}

 {#if gallery.id ==offerId} ........

Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

If you use [the default Svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) to make your app you will see that the `main.js` exports something called `app`. This is the code that is available from outside Svelte to the rest of the page.

In `rollup.config.js` there there is a field `output.name` (by default *app*) this is the name with which the export from `main.js` will be known.

With those two parts we could easily change `main.js` to the following:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

export default function(target, props) {
    new App({
        target,
        props
    })
};
```

What we have here is that insead of immediately mounting our app, we have a function that allows for the creation of apps instead!

So now your backend can generate the html output like this:

```html
<script>
  app(document.getElementById('A'), propsA)
  app(document.getElementById('B'), propsB)
  app(document.getElementById('C'), propsC)
</script>
```

and it will load the app three times, in the specified divs, with the given props.

Now you can of course also print out those props during the backend render as you want, how the actual usage would be is different from platform to platform (in your case Laravel)

Just note that you have to be sure the entire DOM has loaded (to be able to find the targets) and the svelte bundle has loaded (for obvious reasons)